# Perform ASync Task only once in Tabbed Activity

Tags: android

I've created a fragment with ASync task inside a Tabbed Acrivity. Everytime I swipe back to that that fragment, ASync task is executed. 
I just want the ASync task to execute once! Is that possble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

```
private static boolean taskDone = false;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ...
   ...

   if (!taskDone){
     executeTask();
     taskDone = true;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the asyncTask.execute() method in the onCreate() function of the activity where your tabs are instantiated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    asyncTask.execute();
}
```